# Change the button hover color in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, button, imagebutton

I'm creating a windows store app and i want to

- change the button color when the mouse hover on the button
- use an image as a button

I am using VS 2012 and using VB.net.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at **stackoverflow.com/about** to see the format of questions so that you can get great answers! Please make sure to post what code you've tried so far to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create  a mousehover event in your code behind and in that you can do whatever you want.
A perfect and precise answer of both of your questions is the following video
[Click here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkSu-GQ1DGg)